# How to update TabControl resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a tab control in my view, bound to an observable collection. But when I call `RaisePropertyChanged` on it nothing gets updated. The tabs enabled do, but the views inside the tabs do not. How do I refresh the views in my Data templates?

```
<TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceListViewModel.SelectedDevice.TabViewModelsCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceListViewModel.SelectedDevice.SelectedTabItemVm}"   >
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:HomeViewModel}">
                        <local:HomeTab/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:ConfigurationViewModel}">
                        <Grid>
                            <local:ConfigurationFileView  Visibility="{Binding Configuration, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
                            <local:ErrorTab  Visibility="{Binding Path= Configuration, TargetNullValue=Visible, FallbackValue=Hidden}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:ExpansionModulesViewModelFactory}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                <DockPanel >
                                    <local:ExpansionModulesList Title="Discovered/Enumerated" 
                                                        DataContext="{Binding DiscoveredModules}" 
                                                       />
                                    <GridSplitter Width="5"/>
                                    <local:ExpansionModulesList Title="User Action Required" 
                                                        DataContext="{Binding FaultyModules}" 
                                                        />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCommandEnabled}">
                                    <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right"             
                                            Command="{Binding CancelExpansionCommand }"
                                            ToolTip="Revert all local modifications by refreshing data from the controller." />                                                                                                                                  
                                    <Separator Width="10"/>

                                    <Button Content="Apply"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"                         
                                            Command="{Binding ApplyExpansionCommand }"
                                            ToolTip="Apply all changes to the controller." />
                                    <Separator/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:LogViewModel}">
                        <local:LogView  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:SignalStrengthViewModel}">
                        <local:SignalStrengthView  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.Resources>

                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>


                <!--End Device List-->
            </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i can't understand why doesn't update your view, i think you must show me your behind code.
any way you can try:

```
            tabControl.UpdateLayout();
```

and

```
            tabControl.UpdateDefaultStyle();
```